# Ethernet card (NIC) not working properly in HP Proliant BL460c G7

Tags: networking, network-adapter, hp-proliant

If I configure my network card in linux to use DHCP then restart the networking init script, it gets stuck after showing

```
* Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces  
* Reconfiguring network interfaces...
```

But if I restart networking with the following steps

```
dhclient -r
rmmod be2net
/etc/init.d/networking stop
modprobe be2net
/etc/init.d/networking start
```

or just reboot the blade then everything works fine.

Also it is unable to detect any DHCP servers running in the network during PXE boot time. Most probably the NIC drivers of my hp blades are not properly configured.

Please suggest a solution to this problem.

Comment: Not programming. No code involved. Understand?

Comment: Sorry, will take care in future.

Comment: But this question is still unresolved and i don't have any option of migrating it to serverfault (its not showing an option).